# How to get RSS feed item count?

Tags: c#, .net, rss, feed

In C#, .NET 3.5, in a Windows Forms application...

How does one get the integer count of the number of items that a given RSS url returns?

Example:
For my blog at: http://forgefx.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

The expected result would be: postCount = 25

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need page size or total item count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Linq;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using(XmlReader source = XmlReader.Create(
                 "http://forgefx.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default")) {
            int count = SyndicationFeed.Load(source).Items.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

(requires a reference to `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll`)

An advantage of using `SyndicationFeed` is that you support RSS and Atom at the same time.

Comment: I doubt this will work at all. If the source implements paging you'll only get page size as a result.

Comment: This won't work without some extra munging, since [SyndicationFeed.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.items.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable` rather than a `Collection`.